# What is the oldest language that we know enough about to construct a plausible sentence in it?

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, comparative-linguistics, reconstruction

One exciting way to track the evolution of our understanding of Proto-Indo-European is to look at the different versions of *Schleicher's fable* from different years. The more time we spend studying the language, the more 'precise' our reconstructions get, even though they might still be quite far off compared to what PIE actually looked like at any given point in its history. The majority of the reconstructions deal with the 'Classical' stage of PIE (many mainstream versions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schleicher%27s_fable#The_Sheep_and_the_Horses)), with some proposing versions of *Scheicher's fable* in Late PIE (somewhat questionable variations on the theme [here](https://academiaprisca.org/indoeuropean/Schleicher-fable.htm)).

Do we have enough information about the (hypothetical) ergative stage of PIE to, in theory, construct a simple, at least remotely plausible sentence in it?
If yes, how old would that be? What would that sentence look like? Is there any even older language that fits the criterion, e.g. maybe Proto-Afro-Asiatic?
If not, what is the oldest stage of PIE that we can feasibly say something in? When would that approximately be?

Comment: If it's hypothetical, we don't have **any** data; only interpretations and hypotheses.

Comment: Fair point @jlawler; edited.

Answer (score 4):

Sumerian and Egyptian are attested in texts from about 3000 BC onwards. These are real languages, not reconstructed ones like PIE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Do you not think PIE was spoken earlier than 3000 BC or do you not consider any constructed PIE sentences to be 'plausible'?

Comment: @Simon Korneev PIE was spoken quite around 3000 BC +/- 500 years.

Comment: @Anixx. How do you know that?

Comment: @fdb I have read papers on that which convincingly show the possible timeframe. This dating is quite solid.

Comment: @Anixx. I contest that.

Comment: @fdb what's the timing according to your opinion?

Comment: [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) *"PIE is estimated to have been spoken as a single language from 4500 BCE to 2500 BCE [\[2\]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language#cite_note-2) during the Neolithic Age, though estimates vary by more than a thousand years."* If you know better then please create a separate post with references so that Wikipedia can be updated with a proper estimate.

Comment: @tripleee. If “PIE” means “the stage reached by the common ancestor immediately before its break-up into daughter languages” then only the most recent of the suggested dates is of interest (in this case 2500).

Comment: Yeah, mainly just trying to get some sort of referenced sources into this is not/is too exchange. The +/- 1000 years bracket of the estimate in Wikipedia should also be taken into account.

Comment: @fdb it is usually considered that at 2500 BC it was late PIE phase, when Helenic, Armenian and Indo-Aryan were still united but many European families branched away.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen in one paper reconstructions of sentences in Proto-Uralic, and I was shocked how much that reconstruction resembled PIE. The most dfferences were in word order and kwe vs ke and the like.

If Proto-Uralic was so close to PIE, and the both had relatively free word order, one can imagine their common ancestor being very close as well, and those sentences very well resembling it.

It is a pity I cannot find that source again now. It had something about Proto-Uralic numerals or Proto-Uralic negative particle and word order.

Comment: "their common ancestor" - The Indo-Uralic hypothesis is speculative at this point, we should not talk about it as if it is fact.

Comment: @A. M. Bittlingmayer I am not talking about Indo-Uralic, but either it or Eurasiatic or other groupping is true. When I saw those sentences it became obvious that the languages were closely cvonnected.